# How to retrieve cell content of textbox when a button is clicked in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my **jqGrid**, I have one textbox and button. I need to save the value of textbox typed by the user, when that button is clicked. I have tried, but I failed to get the output.

The following is my **colModel**:

```
{ name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "text", formatter: generateTextBox },
{ name: 'Checkout', index: 'Checkout', width: 120, editable: true, formatter: generateCheckoutBtn }
```

I have written custom formatter to generate textbox and button, the code as follows,

```
function generateTextBox(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="15" />';
    }
```

Then I have written a function to retrieve the value of textbox and called that in **onclick**  inside **generateCheckoutBtn** formatter, as follows

```
function generateCheckoutBtn(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<button onclick="return getTextBoxValue(' + rowObject.Id + ')">Checkout</button>';
    }
```

**getTextBoxValue** function, as follows

```
function getTextBoxValue(SelectedId) {            
        alert("RowId: " + SelectedId);
        var txt = jQuery("#CheckList").jqGrid('getCell', SelectedId, 'Price');
        alert("" + txt);
    }
```

The function returns **rowId** correctly, checked using alert, but it returns alert for **txt** as,

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="15" />
```

I don't know how to get the cell content typed by the user in the textbox, and then to save it to database. As well as I have to make an **alert** when the user clicks **Checkout** button without typing the text.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Fiddle will be nice to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For input, maybe you can give a name for it...

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="15" name="yourtxtboxname" />
```

And then pass it using the name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish each individual textbox with a unique ID. Concatenate the textbox id with the rowId in your formatter:

```
function generateTextBox(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"15\" id=\"textbox" + options.rowId + "\"/>";
}
```

Then us a regular selector when retrieving the value inside the textbox:

```
function getTextBoxValue(SelectedId) {            
    alert("RowId: " + SelectedId);
    var txt = $("#textbox" + SelectedId).val();
    alert("" + txt);
}
```